# jQuery pass input value based on table row

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I know very little jquery so please excuse me if I don't make much sense.

I have a table that it's rows are populated from a php db query (the number of rows will vary) in this case there are two rows of data. Here is a portion of the php generated html table.

```
<table border=1 width=800px id=workout>
 <tr>
 <th width=300px id=clients>Client</th>
 <th width=200px id=movements>Movements</th>
 <th>X Completed</th>
 </tr>

<tr>
<td><input type="hidden" name="client_id[]" class="clientval" value="1"></td>   
<td>
<select name="movement[]" width=200 class='typeval' onchange='changeMovement()'>
              <option value="select">Select...</option>
              <option>Key Movement</option>
              <option>Movement -1</option>
              <option selected="selected" >Movement -2</option>
              <option>Movement -3</option>
              <option>Movement -4</option>
        </select>
</td>
<td><label id="count"></label></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input type="hidden" name="client_id[]" class="clientval" value="8">
<td>
<select name="movement[]" width=200 class='typeval' onchange='changeMovement()'>
              <option value="select">Select...</option>
              <option>Key Movement</option>
              <option>Movement -1</option>
              <option selected="selected" >Movement -2</option>
              <option>Movement -3</option>
              <option>Movement -4</option>
        </select>
</td>
<td><label id="count"></label></td>
</tr>
```

I am passing the values of `movement` and `client_id` to a `POST` jquery so I can run a php query on the data and return result. How do I pass along the value of selected movement and client_id based on the row that the select menu is in.

For example: if user changes movement drop down menu on the 2nd row I want to send the `client_id` and the `selected>Movement<` to the jQuery function. Right now it is just getting the first row of my table and that is all.

Here is my edited jQuery:

Edited:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var typeval,clientval, class_id;
$('.typeval').on('change', function(){
    movement =  $(".typeval option:selected").val();
    client_id = $(this).parents('tr').find('input.clientval').val();
    class_id = $(<? echo $class_id; ?>).val();

    //console.log($(this).parents('tr').find('input.clientval').val(), $(this).val());
    $.ajax(
    { url: "movement_count.php",
      type: "post",
      data: {typeval:typeval, client_id: clientval, class_id :},
      dataType: "json",
      });

    success: (function(output) {
    alert(output);
    $(".count").html(output);
    })
 });

</script>
```

Comment: You can add the input hidden into the same table data. Then do something along the lines of this.parent().find(".class")

Comment: Also, why set the data to a string instead of an object? { movement: movement, client_id: client_id, class_id: class_id }

Comment: If you leave your data as a string, you need to add "&" between variables: "movement="+movement+"&client_id="+client_id+"&class_ID"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you need to do the following:

**1.** Remove all `onchange='changeMovement()'`, you won't need them anymore.

**2.** Just `echo` the `class_id` from PHP.

**3.** Fix the way you get the `client_id` as below.

**Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.typeval').change(function() {
        var movement = $(this).val();
        var client_id = $(this).parent().siblings().find('.clientval').val();
        var class_id = <?php echo $class_id; ?>;

        /* Do your AJAX call here */
    });

});​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using jQuery I'd do it like this. Remove the inline JavaScript and bind to the change event of the select elements.

```
var typeval,clientval;
$('select.typeval').change(function() {
    //console.log($(this).parents('tr').find('input').val(), $(this).val());
    typeval =  $(this).val();
    clientval = $(this).parents('tr').find('input').val();
});​
```

- `$(this).parents('tr').find('input').val();` //will give you the
  client_id
- `$(this).val();` // will give you the value of the select item

You can then just drop those values into your AJAX call.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/suNPQ/1/)**

Comment: There are other hidden `input` in the table will that still work or do I some how need to target just the input that contains the `client_id`?

Comment: You can modify it to be `$(this).parents('tr').find('input.clientval').val()` which should pickup the one you need. That will get the hidden input in the same row as you clicked. If there are more then one hidden input fields in each row that have that class let me know.

Comment: I posted my edited jQuery above. Im not getting a `typeval` not defined error. What I have done wrong?

Comment: Oh, you just pasted my example into your code which won't assign any variables. What you want to do is create a pair of global variables and change them in the code I posted in my answer (console.log is only for development). Then in your AJAX call where you have `typeval:typeval, client_id:clientval`, use the global variables. I'll update the code in my answer a bit.

Comment: Does the `function changeMovement` go away now?

Comment: It can because you're moving the inline JavaScript onchange calls into the one jQuery function, so you then want to put any other code you need from that function into the jQuery onchange function.

Comment: I feel really helpless with this. I posted my new jQuery above. What am I missing now. I have tried to make sense of your comments but I just dont understand enough of to make too many changes.

Comment: Are you getting errors now? What happens with the last update?

Comment: No errors but nothing happens when I select a different option in the `select` menu. Its not getting any of the post values.

Comment: I'm about to leave and this thread is growing kinda long. Hit me up via email if you need more help.

Comment: I really appreciate all the help. Where can I find your email address?

Comment: I would like to email you if you dont mind. I messed with it a little this weekend but it's still not working.

Comment: Check my profile which will get you to one of my sites. A contact email is listed there.

Comment: I just sent my email through your contact form at notonebit.com. Once you reply I'll send over my current code.

Comment: I updated my jQuery above. I do not get any errors, but it is not getting any of the `POST` data. Here is my email: threezerofour@gmail.com Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Give your select and input elements a unique id using php.  Something like:

```
<input type="hidden" id="client_id$client_id" ...

<select name="movement[]" id="mov$client_id" ...
```

Then in your javascript function use php to include the client_id like this:

```
changeMovement(client_id)
```

then you can use the client_id to change whatever movement that corresponds like this:

```
var client = $("#client_id"+client_id).val();
var movement = $("#mov"+client_id).val();
```

For the unique ID, you probably want to use whatever variable is populating the value field of your hidden inputs of each row.  I say that without knowing exactly where those numbers are coming from.

Answer (score 0):

Using James' solution it would look like this:

then the jquery looks like this:

var movement = this.value
   var client_id = this.parent().find(".clientval")

Answer (score 0):

Check this working example..   http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/BZ5Wt/

You can get the ClientId of the selected row by using this line..

```
var client = $(this).parent().parent().find('.clientval').val();
```